# extract predictions for individual predictors

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

With a simple model such as

```
lm.mod <- lm(mpg ~ disp + hp, data=mtcars)
```

I'm looking for a way to plot separately 1) the association between `disp` and `mpg` and 2) the association between `hp` and `mpg`.

I can extract predictions using the `predict` function, but these will be for the model that includes both `disp` and `hp`. However, can I extract predictions based on the estimates of `disp` or `hp` alone, so that I can visualize their relative contributions to the model?

Comment: You could just look at their coefficients? Of course you could also predict sets of values where only one of them is not zero or fit new models with only one explanatory variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **pdp** package to create partial dependence plots:

```r
library(pdp)
lm.mod <- lm(mpg ~ disp + hp, data=mtcars)
partial(lm.mod, pred.var = "disp", plot = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
partial(lm.mod, pred.var = "hp", plot = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>